# query inside views of codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, view, models

I have problems populating data from database.
I query inside views

```
$list = $this->ctrlzxc->queryZXC($zxc['id']); //query    

 <?php foreach($list as $li): ?>
                    <?=$ldtls['dateAdded']?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

its not populating the result.

Comment: We'll need more info than that...  other than the `$li` doesn't match `$ldtls` there's no way for us to help

Comment: use $li['dateAdded'] instead of $ldtls['dateAdded'], but do all your query in model not in view